# Как получить данные от пользователя php

Tags: php

Можно ли получить данные от пользователя, не используя html формы? Благодарю за ответы.

Comment: post/get - это не формы. А формы - это не post/get

Comment: post/get это способ передачи данных из формы. Может вопрос не совсем корректен, но суть думаю вы поняли

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, можно. Например методом GET данные можно передать в виде ссылки(URL). Все что идет после "?" - это как раз и есть GET-данные. Второй вариант используя JS + AJAX, можно передать как в GET так и POST.